# Android OnClickListener not working when run

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm working create application for share to facebook, twitter and other social network. Nothing error in my source code, but when I run the application in emulator button with onClickListener not working. Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
Profile profileMap;
List<Photo> photosList;

Button update;
EditText edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    textview.setText("Welcome to Share Application experiment");

    Button share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sharebutton);
    share.setText("Share");
    share.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    share.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_gradient);

    adapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());


    adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.TWITTER, R.drawable.twitter);


    adapter.addProvider(Provider.LINKEDIN, R.drawable.linkedin);


    adapter.addProvider(Provider.MYSPACE, R.drawable.myspace);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.YAHOO, R.drawable.yahoo);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.YAMMER, R.drawable.yammer);


    adapter.addProvider(Provider.FOURSQUARE, R.drawable.foursquare);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.GOOGLE, R.drawable.google);


    adapter.addProvider(Provider.SALESFORCE, R.drawable.salesforce);
    adapter.addProvider(Provider.RUNKEEPER, R.drawable.runkeeper);


    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.FOURSQUARE, "http://socialauth.in/socialauthdemo/socialAuthSuccessAction.do");

    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLE, "http://socialauth.in/socialauthdemo");

    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.SALESFORCE, "https://socialauth.in:8443/socialauthdemo/socialAuthSuccessAction.do");

    adapter.addCallBack(Provider.YAMMER, "http://socialauth.in/socialauthdemo/socialAuthSuccessAction.do");

    adapter.enable(share);      
}

private final class ResponseListener implements DialogListener{

    @Override
    public void onBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Share-Button", "Dialog Closed by pressing Back Key");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Successful");

        final String providerName = values.getString(SocialAuthAdapter.PROVIDER);
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Provider Name = " + providerName);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, providerName + "connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
        edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTxt);

        update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                adapter.updateStatus(edit.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message posted on " + providerName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ShareButton", "Authentication Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }   
}
}
```

and here's my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/topbar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="7dp"
android:background="@drawable/blue_gradient"
>   
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="Share Button"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
</LinearLayout>
<View
    android:id="@+id/view01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
    android:background="#313437" />      
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view01"
/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/dialogTitle"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="Share Update"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"    
/>  
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/editTxt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:hint="Enter Message"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dialogTitle"
/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/update"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="#147af8"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="Update"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTxt"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTxt"
/>

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/layout_gradient"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>    
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/sharebutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
/>     
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone tell me where I got wrong with my project ? Thank you.

Comment: which button click not working ?

Comment: I don't see any onClickListener attached to share button

Comment: on share button to authenticate with social network, and I use update button to update status on social network but when I click update button it won't work

Answer (score 1):

```
 update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update);
```

Move this code to `onCreate()` .Hope this will solve your issue .

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your update button and set the onClickListener in your onCreate method not onComplete